# Calculating time difference for sets of streaming data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function that renders a row based on streaming SignalR data coming from another component:

```
let prev
let next

renderRow = () = {
    this.props.incomingData.map(item => {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{item.time}</td> //00:00:00 format
                <td>{this.calculateSecondsTaken()}</td> //should show the time difference in seconds
                <td>{item.event}</td>
                <td>{item.message} <br/>{item.outputURL}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })
}
```

I'm trying to get the time difference for each data row based on the item.time attribute value by subtracting current time from previous time (in the row).

```
//calculates the difference between the previous and the incoming (next) time value to give the time taken
//for the current row's data to come in.
calculateSecondsTaken = (prev, next) => {
    next - prev;
}
```

I know in the above function it has to be some sort of a subtraction based on previous and next values of time but I can't quite pin down the logic of it. For instance, what would the difference be for the very first row etc.

Edit:
The data streaming component is as follows

```
deploymentEventMessageReceived = (item: DeploymentEvent) => {
    let dataset = {
        time: item.UtcNowPrettyText, //this is the time value
        event: item.EventName,
        message: item.Message,
        outputURL: item.OutputUrl
    }
    let newDataArray = this.state.receivedData.concat(dataset);

    this.setState({
        receivedData: newDataArray
    });
}
```

`deploymentEventMessageReceived()` in turn gets called inside the function where I'm connecting to SignalR.

Edit 2 updated (working version):

```
deploymentEventMessageReceived = (item: DeploymentEvent) => {
  let lastEntryTime;
  newArray = newArray.concat(item);

  if (newArray.length == 1) {
    lastEntryTime = moment(newArray[newArray.length - 1].UtcNowPrettyText)
  } else {
    lastEntryTime = moment(newArray[newArray.length - 2].UtcNowPrettyText)
  }

  timeDiff = moment(item.UtcNowPrettyText).diff(lastEntryTime, "seconds");

  //create new object with the addition of TimeDifference attribute
  let dataset = {
    UtcNowPrettyText: item.UtcNowPrettyText,
    EventName: item.EventName,
    Message: item.Message,
    OutputUrl: item.OutputUrl,
    TimeDifference: timeDiff
  }

  //store it in a new array
  finalDatasetArray = finalDatasetArray.concat(dataset);

  this.setState({
    receivedData: finalDatasetArray
  });
}
```

Inside render() of data streaming component

```
<RenderRow receivedData={this.state.receivedData} />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Apologies, bad question on my part. So you're saying you want to take the very last element on the array from `this.props.incomingData` and subtracting it from the time upon the new entry you're about to receive?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Is `calculateSecondsTaken` in the parents component of `renderRow`? What does your data streaming function look like? How are you adding it to an array that ultimately gets passed to `renderRow`?

Comment: I have updated the original post with more info.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a time difference calculation this way: I keep track of `Date.now()`, which I don't render but keep it in each entry so I can perform math on it. I don't know how you're planning on rendering the time difference, but I put it in `this.state` in my example.

```
deploymentEventMessageReceived = (item) => {
    let dataset = {
        time: item.UtcNowPrettyText, //this is the time value
        event: item.EventName,
        message: item.Message,
        outputURL: item.OutputUrl,
        date: Date.now()
    }
    let lastEntry = this.state.receivedData[this.state.receivedData.length - 1]
    let timeDifference = dataset.date - lastEntry.date //time in ms
    let newDataArray = this.state.receivedData.concat(dataset);

    this.setState({
        receivedData: newDataArray,
        timeDifference: timeDifference
    });
}
```

edit: My personal implementation would be to actually split up the two concepts. I keep `Date.now()` and make a different function to actually build the array of time differences. Never know if you will need `Date.now()` later on, and it just makes more sense to have a timestamp in its entirety in your data. You don't need to add the `item` immediately. You can concat it later. I use object destructuring to make the assignment cleaning as 2 one-liners.

```
deploymentEventMessageReceived = (item) => {
  let { UtcNowPrettyText, EventName, Message, OutputUrl } = item
  let dataset = { UtcNowPrettyText, EventName, Message, OutputUrl, Date: Date.now() }
  this.setState({receivedData: this.state.receivedData.concat(dataset)})
}

buildTimeDifferences = (entries) => {
  let newArr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    if (i !== entries.length - 1) {
      newArr.push(entries[i + 1].Date - entries[i].Date)
    }
  }
  return newArr
}


d = [{Date: 1},{ Date: 2}, {Date: 4}, {Date: 7}]
console.log(buildTimeDifferences(d))
```

Comment: `let lastEntry = this.state.receivedData[this.state.receivedData.length - 1]`
`let timeDifference = Date.now() - lastEntry.date //time in ms` don't see how this'll work, since `this.state.receivedData` is an empty array at the beginning.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty I had a feeling you'd ask that question. If you think my logic is appropriate for your needs, I'm sure you can get the code working with a conditional or two ;).

Comment: I hear you! Now can you explain why you put Date.now() inside dataset?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty A reason that makes no sense. Should definitely be `dataset.date`. Will update now.

Comment: I have fiddled with your solution and got it working but when I update state, all the previous values of time difference gets updated to the latest one. I need a way for it to persist the previous values. Any idea?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty Oh, I thought the entire point was to only have the new value. Why not keep pushing the time differences into an array then?

Comment: I did that but it messes up the final table. How is it that the rest of the data in the row persists but the timeDifference keeps getting overwritten? I've updated original post to show my latest working.

Comment: I made some further changes to the function and now it seems to be working fine, although I'm not sure how elegant or efficient my solution is. Take a look at the edit 2 update.